# How to write a function distance_matrix which computes the distance matrix of a graph without using NetworkX functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, distance, adjacency-matrix

I have to write a write a function distance matrix in python which computes the distance matrix of a graph. I can use the NetworkX function adjacency_matrix to compute the adjacency matrix of the input graph, but I cannot use any other NetworkX functions.

I know that the function has to computes the distance matrix of a graph. It needs to a matrix, represented as an array of type numpy.ndarray, of the same shape as the adjacency matrix of the graph.

```
Am = np.eye(48)
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).toarray()
A1 = np.eye(48)
def distance_matrix(G):
    for m in range(1,49,1):
        Am=np.linalg.matrix_power(A,m)
        for i in range(48):
            for j in range(48):
                if Am[i,j]>0 and A1[i, j] == 0 :
                    A1[i, j] = m and np.diagonal(B)==0 
        return A1
print(distance_matrix(G))
```

I know that the diagonal has to be equal to 0 and the rest of the entries have to be shortest path from one node to the other. I think...

Comment: What kind of distance matrix? Euclidean? Is this for all types of graphs or just DAGs?

Answer (score 1):

Changing a bit the floyd_warshall_predecessor_and_distance function from networkx source code is posible to calculate de distance matrix :

```
def distance_matrix(G, weight='weight'):
    from collections import defaultdict
    #G is a graph from networkx package.
    dist = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(lambda: float('inf')))
    for u in G:
        dist[u][u] = 0

    undirected = not G.is_directed()
    for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True):
        e_weight = d.get(weight, 1.0)
        dist[u][v] = min(e_weight, dist[u][v])

        if undirected:
            dist[v][u] = min(e_weight, dist[v][u])

    for w in G:
        for u in G:
            for v in G:
                if dist[u][v] > dist[u][w] + dist[w][v]:
                    dist[u][v] = dist[u][w] + dist[w][v]

    return dict(dist)
```

Comment: nfmcclure, thank you for the revision but the edges are dictionaries and sometimes the key is not the string 'weight'. Thats why is default but it can be different. That's why i'll undo your revision, please correct me if that's a mistake.